# Integrating JMeter test with Azure Devops for automated run for JDBC

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, performance-testing, jmx, cicd

I have a test plan to do performance testing for my Database. So I have configured my JDBC test plan in Apache JMeter and executed successfully on my local which works fine.

Now I want to integrate it with my azure Devops CI Pipeline. And I configured my pipeline and the pipeline report shows

```
'java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver'
```

The same works on my local, because I have placed the jdbc driver inside apache-jmeter-5.4.1\lib.

How can we achieve this in Azure devops? (I have placed my JMX file in my repo)

Answer (score 0):

If its "**your** azure Devops CI Pipeline" you should add a step somewhere which will download the [Denodo JDBC Driver](https://community.denodo.com/drivers/jdbc/34) and either place it to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation in Azure DevOPS (or any other location under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))

For example you can add Denodo JDBC Driver along with your .jmx script and set `search_paths` property via -J command-line argument pointing to the driver location like:

```
jmeter -Jsearch_path=. -n -t test.jmx .....
```

More information:

- [Classpath Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#classpath)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)